# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HOUGH_GRADIENT', cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT not fixing the issue

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror

Getting an attribute error when trying to run the following code:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np 


def main():
    img = cv2.imread('images/g1.jpg',0);

    print(img)

    img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried to look up a solution to this problem and I substituted the `cv2` with `cv` in

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

however, I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the attribute is

```
cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT
```

So you need to do

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The new answer is

`circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)`

per http://answers.opencv.org/question/177506/cv2-has-no-attribute-cv_hough_gradient/